# StyleCop Integration With SonarQube

Tags: c#, asp.net, jenkins, sonarqube, stylecop

I am attempting to get Stylecop to work with Sonar so I can analyze my ASP.NET application. I am currently running Sonar 4.3 and using the C# 3.0 plugin for Stylecop integration. I am assuming that the C# plugin has made the dedicated StyleCop plugin from the SonarQube Ecosystem plugins obsolete, correct?

I am triggering the sonar analysis through Jenkins.

In the StyleCop subcategory within the C# plugin I have pointed to Both MSBuild.exe and StyleCop.dll 
When I restart my Sonar server, I am seeing the message "All Stylecop rules are disabled, skipping its execution." in my Sonar logs.

When I go to the Quality Profiles menu, the C# rules I have available are the default "Sonar Way" ones.

I have tried looking through the documentation, but it is hard to follow because the documentation isn't kept up to date with the Sonar Updates.

Any help in getting this to work is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with it also, the documentation is poor and the public forum seems to only care about Java and other open source languages. Not much support on there for .net projects.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have installed the StyleCop SonarQube plugin, you need indeed to go to the Quality Profiles menu, then pick the default quality profile (which by default is "Sonar way").

From there, you can search for all "StyleCop" rules by using the filters "Repository: StyleCop", and "Activation: Inactive".

You then can enable specific StyleCop rules by hitting the checkboxes, or all of them using "Bulk Change" on the right.

Comment: Name or key? ... wildcards? The answer above is not enough, it yields ZERO results!

Comment: Did you install the StyleCop SonarQube plugin?

Comment: Eventually in the end I got it working but was not happy with the results.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz The filters are the ones in the left panel (i'm using sonar v 5.1.1). Once you are in the Rules section of the Sonar Way C# quality profile,  you need to untick the "Quality Profile" filter, and tick the Repository filter, and once it opens, check the "Style Cop" option.
Couldn't find the filter for active/inactive though.

Answer (score 0):

in SonarQube go to

**Quality Profiles** -> **C#** -> **Sonar way**

from the top filters, select "**Activation**" -> "**Inactive**" then click "**Search**"
Then you can click check-box to activate the rules that are the currently inactive, or you can use the "Bulk Change" feature to activate all.